# How to pass a function as props from function component to class component

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-component

I have 2 components. The parent component is the function component. It has an arrow function that navigates to another route. And I want to pass that arrow function to a child component, which is a class component. but I don't know why it seems doesn't work, when I use it in the class component, it doesn't navigate. Maybe I pass props wrongly or something.

Parent component

```
function MyEditorFunction() {

    let location = useLocation();
    let query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const navigation = () => {
        navigate(`/Profile?id=${query.get('id')}`)
    }
    return (
        <div className='MyEditorFunction'>
            <MyEditor userId={query.get('id')} navigate={navigation} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Child component

```
class MyEditor extends React.Component {
   handleClick{
     this.props.navigate
   }
  render() {
    return (
       <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
    )
  {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `class component` as follows. Get `navigation` function from `this.props` and pass it to `onClick` prop in `button`.

```
class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return <button onClick={navigation}></button>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, in onClick, I want to do many things, its like
onClick = {this.abc} and 
abc = () => {  many things to do, navigate}. So how can I write navigation in that abc